# Change multiple character in a string C++

Tags: c++, eclipse, c++11, visual-c++

Good morning everyone, a few days ago I'm thinking and I can not find the solution.

I need to change several characters in a string, using only the string class.

I try to use the replace function but only substitutes a character.

Example:

ORIGINAL STRING: "Hola Pepe, com va la vida"

Enter the caracters to replace
a e i o u
Enter the character for which to replace it
*

H * l * P * p *, c * m v * l * v * d *

Thanks all.

Comment: Why don't just iterate through all the string and change the character if necessary?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far. SO is not a code writing service, Please also read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Kinyu 96  Use method find_first_of

Comment: @Kinyu 96   " a few days ago I'm thinking' - You should think more frequently.:)

Comment: Remove the Good Morning from the begin of your question, reading the question at midnight, :-)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: That's not appropriate comment.  The OP is clearly not a native English speaker, but it is clear enough that he meant "I have been thinking about this for a few days". (Yes, I appreciate you meant it light-heartedly, but given the extent of his English skills, the joke probably went right over his head.)

Answer (score 6):

I'd say the most readable way to do what you want is using [`std::transform`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/transform/):

```
#include <algorithm>
...
std::set<char> vowels = {'a', 'o', 'e', 'i', 'u'};
char change_to = '*';
std::string s = "Hola Pepe, com va la vida";
auto transformation_operation = [vowels, change_to](char c)
{
    return vowels.count(c) ? change_to : c;
};
std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), transformation_operation);
```

Here `transformation_operation` is a lambda which actually transforms one char in the desirable way (may be implemented in form of a function or class, if you wish). To do so, it uses set of `vowels` and character `change_to` which are captured. To add some more detail, it checks whether or not the character is present in the `vowels` set and, if present, returns `change_to`, and if not - returns the original character.

`std::transform` calls this lambda for each element from `s.begin()` to `s.end()` storing the result starting with `s.begin()`, that is, in place.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use `std::string`'s method `find_first_of`.

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string s("Hola Pepe, com va la vida");
    std::string t("aeiou");
    char c = '*';

    std::cout << s << std::endl;

    for (std::string::size_type pos = 0;
        (pos = s.find_first_of(t, pos)) != std::string::npos;
        ++pos)
    {
        //s.replace(pos, 1, 1, c);
        s[pos] = c;
    }

    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

The program output is

```
Hola Pepe, com va la vida
H*l* P*p*, c*m v* l* v*d*
```

If to use standard algorithms then I think the most appropriate algorithm in this case is `std::replace_if`. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::string s("Hola Pepe, com va la vida");
    std::set<char> t({ 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' });
    char c = '*';

    std::cout << s << std::endl;

    std::replace_if(s.begin(), s.end(),
        [&t](char c) { return t.count(c); }, c);

    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

The program output is the same as shown above

```
Hola Pepe, com va la vida
H*l* P*p*, c*m v* l* v*d*
```

Comment: Solution with `std::find_first_of` will have poor performance on large strings

Comment: @alexeykuzmin0 For large strings you can use std::replace_if as I showed in my answer.